# checkbox foreach remove exact items from first wrapper and modal with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a wrapper that have some lis with class="ad-item". in each of these lis i have a checkbox. if a checkbox checked it gets that checkbox li and send it to the modal. and If already checked checkbox clicked again to make uncheck it should delete that li from modal.

I know how to add items to modal but don't know how to remove that li from modal with unchecked in first wrapper.

this is my html and js so far:

```js
        $('.add-to-modal').each(function () {
          $(this).change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
              $(".modal").append($(this).closest('.item').clone());
            }
            else {
              $(".modal").find($('.item')).remove();
            }
          });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="first-wrapper">
    <li class="item">
        <p>title 1</p>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="123" class="add-to-modal">
         add to modal</label>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <p>title 2</p>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="125" class="add-to-modal">
         add to modal</label>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <p>title 3</p>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="163" class="add-to-modal">
         add to modal</label>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <p>title 4</p>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="223" class="add-to-modal">
         add to modal</label>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="modal">

</ul>
```

my exact problem is in jquery with

```
else{
$(".modal").find($('.item')).remove();
}
```

this code will remove all items.

also if I use `$(this)` it refers to the checkbox from first-wrapper.

note that if you want to use checkbox value, all items are dynamic and not have these values

another question is how can I create a button in each item of modal that if i click on it. the modal item remove and the same item in first wrapper checkbox make unchecked.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because your code is removing *all* `.item` elements when any single one is deselected, not just the actual checkbox which was interacted with.

You can solve the problem, and make your code much more simple and succinct, by using `map()` to build an array of all the `li` which contain checked boxes when any one of them is interacted with, then using this to set the content of `.modal`:

```js
const $modal = $('.modal');
const $checkboxes = $('.add-to-modal').on('change', e => {
  let modalContent = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map((i, cb) => $(cb).closest('.item').clone()).get();
  $modal.html(modalContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="first-wrapper">
  <li class="item">
    <p>title 1</p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="123" class="add-to-modal">
      add to modal
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <p>title 2</p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="125" class="add-to-modal">
      add to modal
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <p>title 3</p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="163" class="add-to-modal">
      add to modal
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <p>title 4</p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="223" class="add-to-modal">
      add to modal
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="modal"></ul>
```

Note that you don't need an explicit `each()` loop. When binding an event handler to multiple elements, jQuery will iterate over all elements for you.

Comment: thanks Rory. can you explain your code more for me to understant? in map you declear i but never use it. is it nessesery?

also can you answer my second question that a aksed on my question?

Comment: 'in map you declear i but never use it. is it nessesery?' Sorry - I don't know what you mean there. Regarding your second question, yes that's possible. Create a single delegated event handler for any buttons you create dynamically, then add them to the DOM when required. If you're having issues with that I'd suggest starting a new question.

Comment: map(i,cb) I mean

Comment: Ah I see - I have to declare `i`, which is the index, in order to access the second property which I need, which is a reference to the checkbox which was clicked.