# jquery ajax search stored checkbox checked items from past results

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

I'm on wordpress and I create a jquery ajax search.

How can I store checked items, so if user checked some items and wants to search multiple times after, if result have some similar items that are checked from past search it should show that checkbox checked

this is my ajax search:

```js
$ = jQuery;

var pafs = $("#post-ajax-filter-search");
var pafsForm = pafs.find("form");

var html;

pafsForm.submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (pafsForm.find("#ajax-input-search").val().length !== 0) {
    var search = pafsForm.find("#ajax-input-search").val();
  }
  var inputData = {
    action: "en_ads_ajax_filter_search",
    search: search,
  };
  // console.log(inputData);
  $.ajax({
    url: ajax_url,
    data: inputData,
    success: function (response) {
      pafs.find(".ajax_filter_search_results__list").empty();
      // console.log(response);
      if (response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          html = ` 
                    <li class="ad-item" data-id="${response[i].id}">
                        <img src="${response[i].poster}" alt="${response[i].billboard}" class="ad-item__image--img">
                        <div class="ad-item__info">
                            <h4 class="ad-item__info--billboard">title: ${response[i].billboard}</h4>
                            <div class="ad-item__info--list">
                              <label class="ad-item__info--item ad-item__info--item-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="${response[i].id}" class="ad-item__info--add-to-modal">
                              add to output</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    `;
          pafs.find(".ajax_filter_search_results__list").append(html);
        }
      }
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

my output is a simple modal that I insert checked items into it by:

```
        const $modalList = $('.en-ads-modal__list');
        const $checkboxes = $('.ad-item__info--add-to-modal').on('change', e => {
          let modalContent = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map((i, cb) => $(cb).closest('.ad-item').clone()).get();
          $modalList.html(modalContent);
        });
```

I believed this is the best way to avoid duplicate items in output and this way is much more organized.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Please update your snippet with relevant HTML and replace the ajax with a mock to make a [mcve]

Comment: This is the past question that I asked that shows the result and the modal that If the user checked, that items goes to modal.

I just add data-id to this qustion and changed some classes. also it is a different qustion.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/76893243/13751093