# wordpress jquery - checked checkboxes create array of objects and create html base on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, wordpress, object

I'm on wordpress and I've write a ajax filter search that result is items that each one have a checkbox that if checked it get that item html and add it to a modal.

I asked a question like this in days before and have answere from a kind guy but my needs changes:

I want to get each checked items info and insert it into a array of objects like this:

```
[
{item: item1, state: state one},
{item: item2 , state: state two}, 
{item: item3 , state: state one}, 
{item: item4 , state: state three}
]
```

And in this case I add unsorted items. I want to sort this array by "state" each time that an object adds to this array. (each item have many value in it like city, location etc. I just simplify my question)

finally this array of objects inserts to modal just like the html before but sorted.

this is my html first wrapper and modal:

```js
const $modal = $('.modal');
const $checkboxes = $('.add-to-modal').on('change', e => {
  let modalContent = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map((i, cb) => $(cb).closest('.item').clone()).get();
  $modal.html(modalContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="first-wrapper">
    <li class="item" data-id="123">
        <p class="title">title 1</p>
        <p class="state">state one</p>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="123" class="add-to-modal">
         add to modal</label>
    </li>
    <li class="item" data-id="125">
        <p>title 2</p>
        <p class="state">state two</p>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="125" class="add-to-modal">
         add to modal</label>
    </li>
    <li class="item" data-id="163">
        <p>title 3</p>
        <p class="state">state one</p>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="163" class="add-to-modal">
         add to modal</label>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <p>title 4</p>
        <p class="state">state three</p>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="223" class="add-to-modal">
         add to modal</label>
    </li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul class="modal">

</ul>
```

Also I want to know how to remove duplicate objects if user wants to search another items and checked same item checkbox; This is so important for me.

after sort result should be like this:

```
[
{item: item1, state: state one},
{item: item3 , state: state one}, 
{item: item2 , state: state two}, 
{item: item4 , state: state three}
]
```

if another checkbox checked for example "item7" from "state two" the object should insert after item2 with state two (and also in html).

this is my past question: [checkbox foreach remove exact items from first wrapper and modal with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76893243/13751093)

thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can perform a custom sort to your checkboxes array (`Array.prototype.sort()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), based on the `.status` element's text:

```js
const $modal = $('.modal');
const $checkboxes = $('.add-to-modal').on('change', e => {
  const checks = $checkboxes.filter(':checked')

  // CUSTOM SORT BASED ON THE "STATUS" TEXT
  const sortedChecks = checks.sort((a, b) => {
    if ($(a).parent().prev().text().trim() > $(b).parent().prev().text().trim()) {
      return 1
    } else if ($(a).parent().prev().text().trim() < $(b).parent().prev().text().trim()) {
      return -1
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  })
  
  
  const objArray = []
  for (const element of sortedChecks) {
    objArray.push({
      item: 'item' + $(element).val(),
      state: $(element).parent().prev().text().trim()
    })
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(objArray))


  const modalContent = sortedChecks.map((i, cb) => $(cb).closest('.item').clone()).get();
  $modal.html(modalContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="first-wrapper">
  <li class="item" data-id="123">
    <p class="title">title 1</p>
    <p class="state">state one</p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="123" class="add-to-modal">
      add to modal</label>
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-id="125">
    <p>title 2</p>
    <p class="state">state two</p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="125" class="add-to-modal">
      add to modal</label>
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-id="163">
    <p>title 3</p>
    <p class="state">state one</p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="163" class="add-to-modal">
      add to modal</label>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <p>title 4</p>
    <p class="state">state three</p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="223" class="add-to-modal">
      add to modal</label>
  </li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul class="modal">

</ul>
```

Comment: I don't use your code but I think it won't get array of objects. I want it not just for sorting but for further purpose. every steps must be started by this array of objects

Comment: Also it needs to remve duplicate objects from array

Comment: I edited my answer to include the objects array `objArray`

Comment: as per the duplicates removal, on which criteria should an item be considered a duplicate?

Comment: in this case each item should have title and state in an object so duplicate must be base on these two parameter

Comment: your edited answere is not base on what I asked. each time an item add or delete it must get that object, push it into an array, sort it, then insert it again in html modal.

You do it seperately.